# Separate individuals with uniformly distributed events from individuals with other type of uneven distributions

Tags: distributions, anomaly-detection

I am working on a project where I have a dataset in which the occurrence of some events are mapped into a two dimensional grid for different individuals.

I would like to separate the individuals where the occurrence of these events seems to be random, and therefore a uniform distribution is present, from other individuals that have an uneven distribution.

However, I have failed to find similar examples in the literature or rather have failed to find a correct term for describing this type of problem for my literature research. Do you know examples where something similar to this has been done? What techniques are used for this kind of problem?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You sure the randomness is uniform in nature, and not normal distributed / Gaussian?

Answer (score 0):

This seems approachable using feature engineering? You seem to indicate that the histogram shape of events for an individual is informative. So you can calculate features on the histogram like:

- Mean and standard deviation
- 10th, 90th etc percentile
- Skew and kurtosis
- [Spectral flatness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_flatness)

Plot these and see if any look to be informative.